# How do you derive the following two summations?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

I tried using the geometric series formula, $$ \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} ar^{n}=a\left (\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r} \right ) $$, but I got $1-2\left ( \frac{1}{2}^{n-1} \right )$ for the first one and $2-2\left ( \frac{1}{2}^{n-1} \right )$ for the second.

Edit: I derived the first answer by doing $1\cdot \frac{1-\left (\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}$, which results in $2\cdot\left(1-\left (\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1} \right)$ = $2-2\left (\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$. Since it starts out as n=1, I did $2-2\left (\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}-1$, so the final answer I got is $1-2\left ( \frac{1}{2}^{n-1} \right )$

Comment: Could you show in more detail how you tried to apply the geometric-series formula? Without that, I'm left guessing where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations are correct.   You just got which problems you were addressing muddled up.

Notice that  $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}2^{-k} = \dfrac{1-2^{-n}}{1-2^{-1}} = (2-2^{n-1})$ answers the *second* problem, *not* the first.

And likewise $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}2^{-k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}2^{-k} -1 = (1-2^{n-1})$ answers the *first* problem, *not* the second.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}a\left (\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r} \right ) = 
\frac {a(n-1)}{1-r}- \frac{1}{1-r}\sum_{n=0}^{n-1} r^n $

$=\frac {a(n-1)}{1-r}- a\frac{(1-r^n)}{(1-r)^2}$   [by multiplying by $\frac{1-r}{1-r}$]

Answer (score 0):

You cite the formula correctly, but you used
$$ \sum_{i=k}^{n-1} r^k "=" \frac{1-z^{{(n-1)^{\text{<- there's the error}}}}}{1-z} $$